# Angular Parse Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I have a list of objects that I would like to filter using chips. The template code looks like this...

```
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip selected="filterValue=='All'" (click)="filterBy('All')">All items</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of items" selected="filterValue=='{{item.name}}'"
    (click)="filterBy(item.name)">
    {{item.name}}
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

I have a property in the `component.ts` called `filterValue` with the default value set to `All` and a method `filterBy`, that merely changes the value of `filterValue` when you click on a chip.
What I expected to happen was that the `selected` attribute would evaluate the expression and return the appropriate value (either true or false). However, as it is currently, it always returns true.

If I were to surround the selected property with square brackets, then I get the error: `[Angular] Parse Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected...`

I've tried using `[class.active]="filterValue=='{{item.name}}'"` but that also returns `[Angular] Parse Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected...`

I know that `{{}}` **never** goes together with `[prop]="..."` or `(event)="..."` but I can't quite figure out how to solve my particular problem. I'd like to know how to use both the selected property of the `mat-chip` and also the `[class.active]` way of going about it. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `[selected]="filterValue==item.name"`?

Comment: Oh that worked. The surrounding quotes were the ones causing the problem. Thank you.